# Can we use static Pojo methods when running tests concurrently?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pojo

Currently, I have set up an automation test framework which performs the following:

1. Executes specific tests concurrently (i.e. x3 tests at the same
   time).
2. The framework uses Cucumber BDD.
3. I need to store and share data across steps.

I need your advice in relation to using static methods and variables when running tests concurrently, will the data be stored correctly even when running the tests concurrently?

```java
public class Chat_Pojo {

    private static String messageToSend;

    public static void storeUniqueMessage(String message) {
        messageToSend = message;
    }

    public static String getUniqueMessage() {
        return messageToSend;
    }

    public static void wipeMessage() {
        messageToSend = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private static String messageToSend;` belongs to `Chat_Pojo` class only, so if you do not want to share that value, you should either modify it with `private static ThreadLocal<String> messageToSend`. In this case each thread will have its own `messageToSend` value. Respectively if you want to get that value, you need to call `set()` or `get()` 
If you want to share that value between threads, you need to synchronize modification methods ( `public static void storeUniqueMessage(String message)` and `public static void wipeMessage()` )

Comment: thank you for your help @Vault23 when using getter and setter methods I'm assuming I would simply need to call `.get()` or `.set()` as the indexing etc is already handled on a thread to thread basis? and using synchronise would just be the sake of applying the keyword synchronized; `public synchronized void storeUniqueMessage(String message)` ?

Comment: according `.get()` and `.set()` i mean `ThreadLocal` class methods to get value, that stored in `ThreadLocal` (read docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)). Yes, adding `synchronized` will be enough